# Wrong SQL Unknown column 'role_user.role_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` JOIN `role_user` ON `users.id` = `role_user.user_id` 
WHERE `role_user.role_id` = 2
```

**schema table `users`:**

[image]

**schema table `role`:**

[image]

Comment: Can you update you question with;    SHOW CREATE TABLE users;     and SHOW CREATE TABLE role_user;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the backticks on the correct positions to escape the [object names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) (table and column names). So you should change your query to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` JOIN `role_user` ON `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` 
WHERE `role_user`.`role_id` = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need backticks *at all* for your query.  Further, I would recommend that you use table aliases.  A more readable form of your query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u JOIN
     role_user ru
     ON u.id = ur.user_id 
WHERE ru.role_id = 2;
```

Everything between the backticks in a single reference.  So,

```
`role_user.user_id`
```

refers to a single column with that name, not the column `user_id` in `role_user`.  You *could* refer to the column you want as:

```
`role_user`.`user_id`
```

but that is overkill -- harder to type and harder to write.  In general, though, give your columns and tables names so they don't need to be escaped.